# reuse directive multiple times in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a reusable directive which will do some operation on click

my directive code is

```
app.directive('share',['$cordovaSocialSharing',function($cordovaSocialSharing)
{ 
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        scope : {

        },
        link : function(scope,elm,attr)
        {
            elm.bind('click',function()
            {
                console.log('called share service');
                });
        }
    };
   }]);
```

only the first instance of the directive is getting executed on click
the remaining instances are getting ignored

Comment: Show a "working" sample in plnkr or jsfiddle or codepen, somewhere the problem can be shown in action, nothing obviously wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

Is correct the html?
Is a attribute directive ( the restrict param is 'A'):

```
<button share>
  Click me!
</button>

<button share>
 Or click me!
</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/18220/

That should work!